# I can not insert a record into firestore database using angular 12

Tags: css, angular, typescript

There is no error showing when i run ng serve or ng build, but it can't still make a record. I am blown away. Please help me.

I can show you some relevant parts in which i made some changes.
i created a student class in model.ts file, then i created an instance of the class in service class. Afterward, in build component of html file i created the submit() method as shown below

model.ts

```
 export class Students{

id!: string;
matricule!:string;
nom!: string;
prenom!: string;
Quartier!:string;
age!:number
```

}

student.service.ts

```
import { AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Students } from './model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {

  constructor() { }

  formData: Students = new Students();
}
```

student.component.ts

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { StudentService } from 'src/app/shared/student.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student.component.scss']
})
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service:StudentService, private firestore:AngularFirestore)
   { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.resetForm();
  }


 
  resetForm(form?:NgForm) {
    if(form!= null) {
        form.resetForm();
    this.service.formData = {
      id:'',
      matricule:'',
      nom:'',
      prenom:'',
      age:0,
      Quartier:''
      
    }
    } 
  }

  onSubmit(form:NgForm)  {
    let data = form.value;
    this.firestore.collection('students').add(data);
    this.resetForm(form);
  }


}
```

student.component.html

```
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="matricule" #matricule="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.matricule" class="form-control" placeholder="Matricule" required>
        <div *ngIf="matricule.invalid && matricule.touched" class="validation-error">Ce chant est obligatoire</div>
    </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
       <input name="nom" #nom="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.nom" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom" required>
       <div *ngIf="nom.invalid && nom.touched" class="validation-error">Ce chant est obligatoire</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="prenom" #prenom="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.prenom" class="form-control" placeholder="Prenom" required>
      <div *ngIf="prenom.invalid && prenom.touched" class="validation-error">Ce chant est obligatoire</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" name="age" #age="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.age" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" required>
      <div *ngIf="age.invalid && age.touched" class="validation-error">Ce chant est obligatoire</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="Quartier" #Quartier="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.Quartier" class="form-control" placeholder="Quartier" required>
        <div *ngIf="Quartier.invalid && Quartier.touched" class="validation-error">Ce chant est obligatoire</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Do some basic debugging and report back. Is your `onSubmit` called? What is the value does `data ` take? Does your `.add(data);` fail  - recommend adding `.catch(err => handleError(err))`.

Comment: thank you very much, it's now working perfectly

Comment: No problem - these things get easier with practice

Comment: Yeah definitly ! Practice makes perfect